# Reverse Proxy with Apache presenting blank page

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, reverse-proxy

I've got one Raspberry Pi 2 Model B running Deluge and Deluge Web UI 24/7. I set up a No-IP free host so I can access the Rasperry Pi to download some data I've stored in a 3TB disk.

I am using Apache2 as the webserver but I am looking forward to change to a Go application I am creating myself.

The WebUI Deluge listening port is **9090**.

I wanted to access Deluge WebUI without having to type :9090 in the end of the hostname (via /del would be ideal).

I read multiple questions on SO where the Reverse Proxies were mentioned. I quickly checked the official documentation.

The changes I've made to my configuration files are the following:

*/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf*

```
ProxyPass /del http://hostname:9090/
ProxyPassReverse /del http://hostname:9090/
```

I also tried **rewrite** in 000-default (but in different times)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /del [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://hostname:9090 [P]
```

Restarted Apache and the result is a blank page whenever I visit http://hostname/del **(via browser)**

Answer (score 0):

#### Forwarding web traffic to a proxy application

Using *Apache ProxyPass*

```
Reverse Proxy

ProxyPass "/del" "http://127.0.0.1/"
ProxyPassReverse "/del" "http://127.0.0.1/"
Forward Proxy

ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy "*">
  Require host localhost
</Proxy>
```

- Test your config for error : `apachectl -t`
- Restart apache web server : `service apache2 restart`

#### Forwarding web traffic to a proxy application

Using *iptables*

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p -tcp -d 127.0.0.1 \
--dport http -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:9090
```

*The above forward all traffic coming to 127.0.0.1 port 80 to 127.0.0.1 port 9090.*

Comment: Changed the 000-default.conf file and I'm now got a 403 Forbidden page from Apache. Quickly added Require all granted to Proxy block and now it's still a blank page, with the Deluge Web UI title and when checking the source code it's exactly the same as if I was accessing through the port 9090, although, Chrome doesn't display anything.